# "Characters" window won't stay closed

Tags: macos

Sometimes when I open the "Characters" window to get access to special characters (e.g., greek letters), it re-opens itself repeatedly.  The re-opening triggers on some actions, but I haven't found any pattern to those actions - sometimes it's typing, sometimes clicking, sometimes changing tabs in a browser.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any suggestions for how to kill that window and make it stay dead?  Since it's an always-front window, the only think I can do is keep closing it over and over again until the problem goes away eventually.

Comment: Does this happen in _all_ the apps where you use the Character viewer, or only specific apps?

Comment: It happens in every app, but the viewer stays associated with that app.  e.g., if I open it in, say, Settings, it won't pop up when I switch to Chrome, but it will be there when I go back to settings